# validating a XML document against a schema

Tags: java, xsd

I need some code sample which shows how i can validate a xml file against a schema...

Below is say my XML document.. "a.xml"

January
    21
    1983

Say the schema against which i want to validate the above xml is as below named "XMLValidationSchema.xsd"

Now can some one help me write the java code that will take these as input and give proper output like if the XML doc is a valid doc as per the schema i specified...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

A simple example using JAXP:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XMLValidator {
    public void validateXML(final String schemaPath, final String xmlToValidatePath) throws SAXException, IOException {

        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Source schemaSource = new StreamSource(new File(schemaPath));
        Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaSource);

        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(xmlToValidatePath));
    }
}
```